# Building something like an affiliate shop?

Tags: ubercart

We want something very much like Amazon in that some providers define their products in a (site-)global catalog and customers can buy from this catalog.
Customers and providers have the standard features expected from such a system (history, various reports etc etc).

A little peculiarity is that there are no payments or shippings in this system. We are responsible for *gathering* the orders from customers and notify the providers. The rest is not up to us.

Which modules do you think we should use to implement such a system ? (Drupal 6)

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged this with ubercart and you're using Drupal 6 so this should be fine - http://drupal.org/project/ubercart_marketplace

If you're not processing payments directly and have some 3rd party integration you're probably best off implementing a custom payment gateway and method using the hooks provided by ubercart than trying to track down a contrib module.